Bump of gcc in mingw introduced dependency on libwinpthread-1.dll in the compiled binaries
I used to have a mingw based on gcc 7.4.0 and binaries that I compiled with it would work just fine. But once I bumped to mingw based on gcc 13.2.0, all the binaries I compile suddenly have a runtime dependency on libwinpthread-1.dll.
I know that there are a few ways around this (static linking, adding mingw64/bin to PATH, or copying the .dll files next to the binaries), but I am curious if there is a better way to resolve this? Or did something change in GCC in the last several major versions that causes this dependency to be there?
I built the mingw myself, using a fork of the original https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries repository.
I've added --static-gcc to the build of mingw as well as --no-strip in an effort to solve this, but the issue persists.
